# Sort a Grails Domain list using a column index instead of column name

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I retrieve rows on the my database through my domain using a code similar to this:

`def DomainList = DomainClass.list(sort: orderBy, order: "asc")`

Assuming that the `orderBy` variable is a `String` that is the name of one of the domain's `column`. But what if I want to sort it by a column index instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

How can I do that on Grails?

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the use case for this? How are you making sure that the columns in the select statement correlate to the index you have in mind? I fail to see how this is used/useful.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore At first I was like that too, but that's a client's request... and ohhhh you know clients...

Comment: orderBy could be a map key,value and you then map.find{it.key=input} and return its value.. to make it less lines.. you could probably hardcode the indexes somewhere and refer to them by the referred value so if their reusable for other services etc

Comment: @vahid Yeah, like using an `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I gave up on finding a *dynamic* solution. Instead, I use an `if-else` trap at the beginning of the code since each index corresponds to a particular column:

```
def orderBy = params?.orderBy
def orderByPolicy = params?.orderByPolicy

if(orderBy.equals("0")) {
    orderBy = "name_of_index_0_column"
}
else if(orderBy.equals("1")) {
    orderBy = "name_of_index_1_column"
}
else if(orderBy.equals("2")) {
    orderBy = "name_of_index_2_column"
}
else if(orderBy.equals("3")) {
    orderBy = "name_of_index_3_column"
}

if(!orderByPolicy?.equalsIgnoreCase("desc")) {
    orderByPolicy = "asc"
}

def DomainList = DomainClass.list(sort: orderBy, order: orderByPolicy)
```

Note though, this is not *dynamic*. It cannot accommodate adding on new columns to the `DomainClass`; you must manually edit also the `if-else` trap.